# How Do I Extract a link of a button that is defined using a class within a '<p>' tag in html using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have been trying to web-scrape a website that does not offer API's and I have ran into a problem where I want the link of a button but the button is not defined using the traditional button or input tags instead it is defined inside a p tag when I used Inspect Element.

When select the p tag it highlights the button but the only thing inside the p tag is the text of the button within a span tag.

The p has some attributes like classes,ng-click,autom,etc

Is there anyway I can get the link of this button using selenium chrome webdrivers in python?

```html
<div class="fr hidden-md" ng-show="flt.totalFare>0 || queryProp.rescId">
    <p class="<classs name>" analytics="<stuff>" yatratrackable="<stuff>" ng-click="makePricing({seg:flt.selectedId, from:'', ttype:queryProp.type},$event,flt);" autom="booknow">
        <span analytics="<stuff>" yatratrackable="<stuff>" class="<class name>">Book
                                Now
        </span>

        <i ng-class="currencyCode=='<code>'?'<cur>':'symbol'" ng-bind-html="currencySymbol" class="rs"><currency>
        </i>&nbsp;5,715</span>
            <i class="<class name>" ng-show="flt.clicked &amp;&amp; conf.pricingOn" style="position: absolute;margin-left:
                                        0;">
            </i>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the exact code of that webpage with some minor changes.

How can I extract the link of this button with selenium?

Inspect Element shows that the button is defined in the 
paragraph tag

Comment: please share the url if possible.

Comment: here : [link](https://flight.yatra.com/air-search-ui/dom2/trigger?type=O&viewName=normal&flexi=0&noOfSegments=1&origin=BOM&originCountry=IN&destination=DEL&destinationCountry=IN&flight_depart_date=23/06/2019&ADT=1&CHD=0&INF=0&class=Economy&source=fresco-home&version=1.24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use to use to access <kbd>Book Now</kbd> button(s).

```
//div[@class='fr hidden-md']//p[@autom='booknow']
```

If you want to select the buttons by index use the index as shown below

```
(//div[@class='fr hidden-md']//p[@autom='booknow'])[1]
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes

Comment: But how do I extract the link out of it? I will only be able to click the button with xpath. The link is not stored in any of the attributes

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by link? There is no link associated to neither `<p>` tag nor parent `<div/>`.

Comment: how do I click the button with this xpath with selenium python

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='fr hidden-md']//p[@autom='booknow'])[1]").click()` should click the first book now button.

Comment: Make sure to use the Expected Condition (EC), so that the script will wait until the `Book Now` button is present, before clicking.

Comment: Ohh thanks got it. My program was not waiting for the page to load. Just added a sleep for 10 seconds now works fine. I also wanted to ask there are 8 links like this on the page how do I click the 2nd one instead of the 1st one? It only click the first button and all the buttons use the same classes

Comment: `(//div[@class='fr hidden-md']//p[@autom='booknow'])[index_goes_here]`.

Comment: And also how do I wait until the button is clicked and the other web page is loaded?

Comment: use the expected condition to wait until the element in the next page is displayed.